# Improper integral with moving parts

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Evaluate the following integral where $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<r<s$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s} dx$$

I tried substitution, its just the $r$ and $s$ sort of mess with me, what's the trick here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/s}$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s}\,dx&=\frac1s\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r/s-1}}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1s B\left(\frac{r}{s},1-\frac rs\right)\\\\
&=\frac1s {\Gamma(r/s)\Gamma(1-r/s)}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi }{s\sin(\pi r/s)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: what's $B$? a neighborhood? lol and is $\Gamma$ the gamma function or

Comment: $B(x,y)$ is the Beta Function.

Comment: ahhhh never heard of this thanks!

Comment: The constraint $0<r<s$ ensures that $\frac rs$ is not an integer.

Comment: @tomi Yes correct.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @MarkViola one question, when going from beta to gamma function, I saw on wikipedia that $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ you didn't do the bottom cause that's just gamma function of $1$ correct? i.e., $\Gamma(r/s+1-r/s)=\Gamma(1)=1$

Comment: Yes, $r/s +1-r/s=1$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$.